# Is Data Analysis/Science good for online freelancing (Upwork, Freelancer...)?

Tags: data-analysis, career

My interest in data analysis/science began about a year ago because it combines statistics, analysis, and programming. Unfortunately, I was surprised that there was almost no demand for it in the job market in my country, which led me to think about freelancing on Upwork, Freelancer, etc. after gaining experience in data analysis/science.

However, I began to wonder, is there a company that would give you its data to analyze? and as you know, data is the most valuable resource for any company.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that there are thousands of Data Analysts working in

- **Freelancer:** https://www.freelancer.com.bd/jobs/data-analytics
- **Upwork:** https://www.upwork.com/freelance-jobs/data-analysis/

But you need to know that companies do not share their data in a random manner. They have strict policies and laws in place to ensure that data privacy is maintained and the data is used for the purpose it's intended for.

If you want to work with the company's data, you will need to convince them that you are trustworthy, skilled, and have a good understanding of data privacy laws and regulations. Because It is hard to find high-value companies at first. You need to reach out to small businesses and startups. And slowly gain expertise and experience.

A small quote for Discipline:

```
“Do the impossible and you’ll never doubt yourself ever again.”
```

Comment: Thank you for the informations. Ok, how can I convince them that I am trustworthy? And where can I gain experience since there is almost no demand in my country for data analysis and science?

Comment: To convince them you're trustworthy, you need to show them you're experienced. To become experienced, you need to take online courses, participate in online communities, volunteer, work on personal projects, and then create a Portfolio.

Comment: They might also give you a privacy laws agreement paper and you need to sign in that. And also don't forget to improve your communications skill as it impacts hugely in the industries.